# Drop Down List that is created by code behind refresh the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-refresh, runatserver, ispostback

I am trying to create a list of `DDL` using code behind as you can see here :

```
public List<DropDownList> ddll = new List<DropDownList>();
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    DropDownList ansList = new DropDownList();
    ansList.AutoPostBack = false;
    ansList.DataSource = values1;
    ansList.DataBind();
    ddll.Add(ansList);
 }
```

As you can see i set the `autopostback` attribute on `false` .But it doesn't work any my pages are refreshed when the user changes the `selectedindex`.

I added `DDL` using this :

```
Span1.Controls.Add(ddll[0]);
Span2.Controls.Add(ddll[1]);
Span3.Controls.Add(ddll[2]);
Span4.Controls.Add(ddll[3]);
Span5.Controls.Add(ddll[4]);
Span6.Controls.Add(ddll[5]);
Span7.Controls.Add(ddll[6]);
Span8.Controls.Add(ddll[7]);
Span9.Controls.Add(ddll[8]);
Span10.Controls.Add(ddll[9]);
Span11.Controls.Add(ddll[10]);
Span12.Controls.Add(ddll[11]);
Span13.Controls.Add(ddll[12]);
Span14.Controls.Add(ddll[13]);
Span15.Controls.Add(ddll[14]);
```

In html code i have this :

```
<span style="color:#ea0000;padding:0 10px;" id="Span6" runat="server"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first set `AutoPostBack` to `false` and later to `true` right after two statements. The `false` is overwritten by `true` and it should do postback now when the selected index is changed.

```
ansList.AutoPostBack = false;
   //...    

ansList.AutoPostBack = true;
```

**Edit** You can also use **loop** to add the list in the spans using [FindControl(string id)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the spans by id.

```
for(int i=0; i < 15; i++)
   this.FindControl("Span"+i).Add(ddll[i]);
```

Comment: Sorry  it was my syntax fault ,i changed it and again same error

Comment: Build the page the refresh it using ctrl+F5 it should not do postback

Answer (score 1):

Look at your code

```
       for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            DropDownList ansList = new DropDownList();
            ansList.AutoPostBack = false; // Here You have set it false
            ansList.DataSource = values1;
            ansList.DataBind();
            ansList.AutoPostBack = true; // Here You have set it true again
            ddll.Add(ansList);
        }
```